# Python3: cx_Oracle - Execute a local procedure

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures

I am working with cx_Oracle in Python3. I am stuck with local procedure part.We have a procedure but its not stored procedure. I have that code locally and not in Oracle server.

How can I execute that procedure and I need to pass argument to that Procedure.

Can I call it from a local file or do I have to place entire procedure code in a file and call it as a query ?

As my server is a live one and I am not trying to do any experiments.

EDIT: This is how my procedure looks like. I have removed few contents but this is the blue print of it

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE insertOrUpdateITEM (ip IN CHAR) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT STATEMENT HERE
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE   
    SET      
    WHERE    
END insertOrUpdateITEM;

BEGIN
insertOrUpdateITEM('192.168.56.101');
END;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have exactly? A `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` code block?

Comment: No , I have DECLARE PROCEDURE.

Comment: Do you mean *anonymous* block?

Comment: I dont know much about oracle things. To understand this issue much better what information I could provide ?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  and David Isla I have updated my post. Please look.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh , We use this on every day activities to add IP into database.

Comment: It looks to me that you're only doing an insert in it. Why not just use plain SQL statement?

Comment: Yes I have same thought initially but as we are using this,I want to follow same process in the script as well.